# What does this circuit symbol mean?

Tags: circuit-design, symbol, guitar-pedal

I'm a student who is trying to build a wah pedal for a guitar. I came across this diagram for how to wire the circuit ([from this site](https://www.electrosmash.com/crybaby-gcb-95)) :
[image: Circuit diagram for wah pedal]

Within the diagram, I am not sure what the following symbol means:
[image: Mystery symbol]

This variant of the symbol also appears in the diagram and I am not sure what to make of it either:[image: Mystery symbol variant]

I'd much appreciate if anyone could explain these symbols to me as the only place I have been able to find these online was on this very circuit diagram and no context is provided as to their meaning.

Comment: @EugeneSh. related, I would say but not a duplicate. The linked question is asking what pin is what. This question is asking what *is* the symbol. That's 2 different questions.

Comment: @MCG The title of that one is the answer to this one, no? So I would say that this question is a subset of the linked one.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Subset is not a duplicate. A duplicate to me is someone asking the same question and would receive the same answers. Therefore, it is not a duplicate. It is certainly related though

Comment: @MCG Well, I don't know how SE is defining it. If someone is asking how much is `1+1`, then it can be definitely closed as a duplicate of a question asking how much is `x+y`. Anyway, we don't have to agree on this  :)

Comment: It's not really a DC ("barrel") jack; given the application this is probably a TS jack, probably the ¼" variety. They have the same symbol, though.

Comment: Also, if you're going to change the question to ask "where is the switch", make it a new question.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yeah, very true! I just said how I would define a duplicate, as an answer from this (This components is *x*) wouldn't answer the question of "I have this *x*, how do I connect it?" But anyway, people always have differing opinions! Usually it's a good thing! :)

Comment: @Hearth, true doing that now.

Comment: Commonly referred to as a "phone jack" (not to be confused with a "phono jack").

Comment: Here's an image, though not of a jack with the built-in switch:  https://www.cigarboxguitar.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/11/Both-Jacks-Annotated.jpg

Comment: This is the switching variety: https://www.allelectronics.com/mas_assets/cache/image/3/4/5/f/13407.Jpg

Comment: For reference, here is a *phono* jack (also known as an "RCA jack"): https://www.mpja.com/images/25522-large.jpg

Comment: The box and line are also part of the symbol.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That signifies a jack with a connection that breaks when a plug is inserted.  In the case of your schematic, that connection isn't connected to anything anyway, so it shouldn't matter.

Comment: The switch is physically inside the jack.  On the schematic it is where the arrowhead touches the line with the kink in it.

Comment: It isn't connected to anything, as signified by the 'X' at the other end.

Comment: @DarthVader If your question is about where the bypass switch is, it is not shown in that schematic at all.  You can see it wired in one of the photos from that link, though. I also have a few of these, that switch is wired to both jacks, shorting them together and cutting out the circuit entirely.

Answer (score 6):

Barrel connector with switch -- 2 conductors, 3 contacts.

[Here](https://www.digikey.com/short/pmnz48) are some similar parts Digi-Key has listed. Most will show a diagram in the data sheet.

[image]

Terminal 1 is the sleeve connection, and terminal 2 is the tip.  Terminal 4 is a switch contact that is connected to the tip when there is no plug inserted, and disconnected when the plug is inserted.